# Codeigniter Form Validation Not Working ZzZ

Tags: php, jquery, forms, codeigniter, validation

FORM

```
<?php echo form_open('account_setting/account_setting_check_pass/', 'class="form-horizontal'); ?>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Change Password</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputCurrentPassword" class="col-lg-0 control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                        <input type="password" name="currentPass" class="form-control"  placeholder="Current Password"  />
                        <?php echo form_error('currentPass','<div class="alert alert-danger">', '</div>'); ?>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputNewPassword" class="col-lg-0 control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                        <input type="password" name="newPass" class="form-control" placeholder="New Password"  />
                        <?php echo form_error('newPass','<div class="alert alert-danger">', '</div>'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputCurrentPassword" class="col-lg-0 control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                        <input type="password" name="newPassConf" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password"  />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function account_setting_check_pass(){

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('currentPass', 'Current Password', 'trim|required|callback_validatePass');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('newPass', 'New Password', 'trim|required|matches[newPassConf]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('newPassConf', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required');


    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){

        redirect('failed');
    }
    else{

        redirect('success');


    }


}

private function validatePass(){

    $user = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $passFromForm = $this->input->get_post('currentPass');

    $passFromDB = $this->get_data->get_user_pass($user);
    if($passFromDB){
        if(password_verify($passFromForm, $passFromDB)){
            return TRUE;
        }
        else{
            $this->form_validation->set_message('validatePass', 'Incorrect Password');
            return FALSE;
        }

    }
    else{
        $this->form_validation->set_message('validatePass', 'Incorrect Password');
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

I just want to validate the password of the user from the database but when I submit the form nothing is happening, but the data from the form is in the URL. although I used POST method in the form the data from the POST is empty but when I try GET the value is there so i tried using GET_POST. Also the validation error isn't showing either. No model yet for changing the password coz i'm stuck in the validation part.
Sample URL when I tried to submit

```
http://localhost/ems/account_setting/account_setting_check_pass?currentPass=qwerty&newPass=qwerty&newPassConf=qwerty
```

I hope someone could help me out, coz i'm finding the error for a couple of hours already
Thanks you so much<3

```
Form filename: account_setting_password
controller: account_setting
function name: account_setting_pass()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `form_open()` call is slightly malformed. According to the [Form Helper documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html), attributes like your `form-horizontal` class need to be passed as an array.

```
$attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal');
echo form_open('account_setting/account_setting_check_pass', $attributes);
```